# Change opacity on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

How do I make it so that the opacity is normal until someone hovers over it and when they hover over it the picture lights up but sends the other images to the background? I also want the images to fade in and out.

[Example](http://www.gazelle.com/)

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx35C/)

```
img { 
opacity: 0.7; 
} 

img:hover { 
opacity: 1; 
}
.radio div[type='radio'] {
background: transparent;
border:0px solid #dcdcdc;
border-radius:10px;
padding:0px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
text-align: left;
opacity: 0.7;
}
.radio div:hover[type='radio'] {
opacity: 1; 
}
```

That opacity is fine but I want the images to have their normal opacity until someone hovers over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple class and this JS to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
$('.radio').on('mouseover mouseout', 'div[type="radio"]', function(){    
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass('hover');
});

.radio div[type='radio'].hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx35C/3/

I removed the image-targeted CSS, as its parent opacity will trickle down. Also added in a transition similar to what Gazelle has.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to contribute a pure CSS solution to this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbMtN/)

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

ul:hover li img {
    opacity: .5;
}

ul:hover li img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

I will go step by step to explain this, first of all sorry for making this from scratch, your HTML was killing me, so coming to the explanation, first am making all the `li` `inline`, than am using `ul li img` and setting all images to `opacity: 1;`, well not required but I did set, later am using `transition` property for smoothing up the animation. The next selector is `ul:hover li img`, will simply make images opaque to `.5` when you hover over `ul` this means it will set opaque all the images to `.5`, and at last we set `opacity` to `1` when you `hover` any image by using `ul:hover li img:hover`

Comment: Ah yes, coming from above. Good one.

Comment: One of my favorite CSS answers ever

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality is better achieved with Javascript. Take a look at this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LgZeB/4/

```
$('.images a').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.images a').not(this).addClass('fade');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.images a').removeClass('fade');
});
```

With jQuery, I'm able to plug into the "mouseover" and "mouseout" functions of the DOM element. Then I can add or remove the relevant CSS class which sets the opacity attribute.

Comment: I'll have to change all my classes. Can you provide an example using my code?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I replaced '.images a' with '.radio div' and nothing happens.

Comment: Ok I added another class called q2 and I put it with the code but it doesn't fade. I need everything to fade.