# Found a issue related to Laravel routing

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, routes

I have issue related to Laravel routing. For example if my site is `xyz.com` and i have link on my home page `<a href="https://www.instagram.com/myprofile/">Instagram</a>`.

Then it does not take me to the Instagram link instead of opening this link it opens the `wwww.servername/laravel/public/https://www.instagram.com/myprofile/` instead. How can I open a new link?

Comment: Have you a base path set on the page itself? Like in the head markup?

Comment: Post the code which generates the anchor tag `<a>` to the Instagram page.

Comment: no and here is the problem i am doing this live on web server. `http://pickprogress.com` at the end of site there is link of `M-ahmed alvi` which is not  working

Comment: just add `target="_blank"` or `target="_self"` to the anchor

Comment: There isn't enough information from you to solve this problem

Comment: please visit the site at the end of site there is link which is not working. can please have a look at it and can tell me where i am doing mistake?

Comment: fabio i tried this but still its not working

Comment: Is the footer in a blade file? It seems the `{{` is still container in the href

Comment: no it's not blade file

Comment: Can you show us the snippet from the section that generates this part of the footer? Please update your question with said information

Comment: `<a href="{{ url('www.facebook.com') }}">M- Ahmed Alvi</a>`

Comment: this is the code in footer

Comment: For blade tags to work `{{ + }}` they need to sit within a .blade file. Please make sure you are including a footer that is a blade file

Comment: ok m going to do that

Comment: Please ensure that you update this question with the appropriately marked answer to allow future viewers to also benefit from this exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is being generated using blade functionality. However based on the discussion in the comments above, the link does not sit within a blade file, and thus the blade functionality, specifically in this case `url`, is not being called.

Please ensure the following:

- Blade functions sit within a .blade.php file
- url is called within the blade markers `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="{{ url('/') }}">Homepage</a>` - This will take u to homepage

`<a href="{{ url('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669259/change-opacity-on-hover') }}">This post</a>` - This will take u to your link in this case this post

Best Regards

Comment: Your first comment about the homepage is correct. The second, the url part is unrequired as you have an absolute address within it

Comment: True it can be written as <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669259/change-opacity-on-hover"